# In pdf.js how do I turn on handtool as the default setting?

Tags: pdf.js

I am using  [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to display a `pdf`. I would like the handtool to be on as the default setting, rather than people having to access it via clicking on the button.

This is the html button code:

```
  <button id="toggleHandTool" class="secondaryToolbarButton handTool" title="Enable hand tool" tabindex="27" data-l10n-id="hand_tool_enable">
              <span data-l10n-id="hand_tool_enable_label">Enable hand tool</span>
            </button>
```

This is the code on the .js document:

```
    var HandTool = {
  initialize: function handToolInitialize(options) {
    var toggleHandTool = options.toggleHandTool;
    this.handTool = new GrabToPan({
      element: options.container,
      onActiveChanged: function(isActive) {
        if (!toggleHandTool) {
          return;
        }
        if (isActive) {
          toggleHandTool.title =
            mozL10n.get('hand_tool_disable.title', null, 'Disable hand tool');
          toggleHandTool.firstElementChild.textContent =
            mozL10n.get('hand_tool_disable_label', null, 'Disable hand tool');
        } else {
          toggleHandTool.title =
            mozL10n.get('hand_tool_enable.title', null, 'Enable hand tool');
          toggleHandTool.firstElementChild.textContent =
            mozL10n.get('hand_tool_enable_label', null, 'Enable hand tool');
        }
      }
    });
    if (toggleHandTool) {
      toggleHandTool.addEventListener('click', this.toggle.bind(this), false);
    }

toggle: function handToolToggle() {
this.handTool.toggle();
SecondaryToolbar.close();
 },
```

Can I add something to my html to turn that on immediately after page load? Or can I change the .js file to do that?

Answer (score 9):

I was just trying to achieve the same thing.

Apparently it's as simple as changing `enableHandToolOnLoad: false` to `enableHandToolOnLoad: true` in `viewer.js`.

Probably this wasn't possible at the time you've posted this question.

Answer (score 3):

OK I worked it out.....

I added:

```
<body onLoad="HandTool.toggle()">
```

to the end of the html, just before

```
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

In viewer.js, turn `cursorToolOnLoad` to `1` in `getDefaultPreferences`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this call once the viewer page is initialized.

```
 PDFViewerApplication.pdfCursorTools.switchTool(1);
```

Select: 0, Hand: 1, Zoom: 2

Comment: Note: Zoom is defined in the code but only gives a `switchTool: "2" is an unsupported value.` message.